# WinSCP: WinSCP Generated PowerShell .Net Assembly code not working. I must be missing something

Tags: powershell, winscp

I'm new to using the PowerShell .Net Assembly, so there is likely a misunderstanding on my part.

I generated PowerShell .Net Assebly code from WinSCP, when I try to use it, I get an error. What am I doing wrong please?

**CODE:**

```
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "sftp site"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "`password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "securitydata"
}

$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("FSProtocol", "2")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    Write-Host $session
    # Set up transfer options
    $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions -Property @{
        TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Ascii
    }
    
    # Transfer files
    #changed 
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
MethodInvocationException: untitled:Untitled-3:19:5
Line |
  19 |      $session.Open($sessionOptions)
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Open" with "1" argument(s): "Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.EventWaitHandle..ctor(Boolean, System.Threading.EventResetMode, System.String, Boolean ByRef,
     | System.Security.AccessControl.EventWaitHandleSecurity)'."
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl!  I see I need to use the .NET Standard build of the WinSCP .NET assembly.  I've read the instructions on the website, but I still don't understand what I need to do.  

Do I place the WinSCPnet.dll from the NetStandard directory in the same directory as the PowerShell .exe?  Then, in the script, do I point the Add-Path to that .dll?  LIke this?

Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\WinSCPnet.dll"

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience understanding how to integrate or install .Net items in PowerShell, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Based on `Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"`, I assume you already have a `net40` copy of the `WinSCPnet.dll`, in the folder where your PowerShell script resides. Replace that copy (or whatever copy your PowerShell script loads) with the `netstandard2.0` version.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I have a <net40> copy of the WinSCPnet.dll, but I just didn't know where to place it.  It looks like it needs to be in the same file location as the PowerShell script that I am running, is that correct?  If so, do I need to use Set-Location in the PowerShell script as well, or is just having it in the same directory as the .ps1 script sufficient?

Comment: The `Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"` loads the dll from *somewhere* (probably the script's folder). So if you replace that copy with the `netstandard2.0` version, it will work with no other effort.